# Xen VM could not be installed

Tags: linux, networking, centos, xen, centos6.5

I have rented a server from Hetzner. I have installed Xen on Dom 0 - Centos 6.5. I couldn't create a Dom1 Centos 6.5 VM.

The Error I see is 'Unable to retrieve 'the link for centos image' while trying to install a Dom1 Centos 6.5 VM.

On Dom 0 :

Interface **xenbr0**

```
[root@static network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-xenbr0

DEVICE=xenbr0
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
STP=off
PIFDEV=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=5.9.*.*
GATEWAY=5.9.*.*
NETMASK=255.255.255.*
DNS1=<removed>
DNS2=<removed>
DNS3=<removed>
NM_CONTROLLED=no
#DEFROUTE=yes
#IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System xenbr0"
```

Interface **eth0**

```
[root@static network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR="<removed>"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="<removed>"
#DEFROUTE=yes
#IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
BRIDGE=xenbr0
```

IPTables configuration

```
[root@static etc]# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables

# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i xenbr0 -o xenbr0 -j ACCEPT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Added this line>>>>>
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Sysctl configuration

```
[root@static network-scripts]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf

# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Changed this line>>>>

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Disable netfilter on bridges.
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

On Dom 1 while installing Centos 6.5 :

```
I selected Manual IPV4 :
IP ADDR : 5.9.*.*
Subnet : *
Name server : Same as DNS1 in Dom0.
Gateway : I used IP of host to be the gateway for Dom 1 (I followed [this tutorial][1])
```

Can someone please help me to get the Dom1 installed on this machine? Thanks!

Comment: Whats the exact command you are using to create Dom1?

Comment: I use xm create -c start-vm.cfg :

name = "mailserver"
memory = "768"
kernel = "/root/mailserver/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/root/mailserver/initrd.img"
disk = [ 'tap2:aio:/root/mailserver/disk-mailserver.img,xvda,w', ]
vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0', ]
vcpus=1
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_crash = 'destroy'

Comment: Can you give me the contents of  /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp ?